# How to set MXNET_CUDNN_AUTOTUNE_DEFAULT?

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

When I test an image use Faster R-CNN in mxnet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78OQz.jpg)

How to set MXNET_CUDNN_AUTOTUNE_DEFAULT?

Answer (score 2):

If you use mxnet in linux or unix,you should set  the environment 
"export MXNET_CUDNN_AUTOTUNE_DEFAULT=1".
If you use mxnet in windows, you should set  the environment 
"set MXNET_CUDNN_AUTOTUNE_DEFAULT=1".

Pls refer to http://mxnet.io/how_to/perf.html.